# Is there a G-force curve estimated for a SLS launch?

Tags: launch, sls, g-force

Has the G-force curve for the launch of [Block 1, Block 1B, or Block 2](https://www.nasa.gov/exploration/systems/sls/overview.html) (crew and or cargo) Space Launch Systems been determined? If there is no published estimates for the curve, is the estimate of the maximum G-force with any of the configurations?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I haven't seen acceleration-vs-time curves published by NASA.

The [SLS Mission Planners Guide](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/citations/20170005323) has a table of maximum expected acceleration. Looks like it is predicted to max out at 4.1 g.

[image]